# How i can do that login button disappear when i login jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a login button. How i can do that when i log in in my application that button "Login" disappear. And appera button appears.

```
<form id="loginForm" class="form-signin">       
          <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Zaloguj się!</h2>
          <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="login" required="" autofocus="" />
          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/></br></br>      
          <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   
        </form>
```

I was useing .hide  and  .remove but that metod leaves free pleace and screan look ugly.
I can use jQuery script? How i can do this i jQuery ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this with jQuery, and it sounds like you are on the right track. Really you want to just hide() the login button, and then show() the next button that will appear. If you remove() the content, then the HTML tags are removed; thus, you get this nasty empty space.

Edit: Imagine your code was this:

```
<form id="loginForm" class="form-signin">       
     <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Zaloguj się!</h2>
     <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="login" required="" autofocus="" />
     <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/></br></br>      
     <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   
</form>
<button id="otherButton" class="etc etc" style="display: none">Something else</button>

//JS
    $("#submitButton").hide(); //Hide submit button
    $("#otherButton").show(); //Show other button
```

I believe that should work!